# What is the correct way for loading an external svg file into a react component so that it can later be dynamically styled by manipulating classes

Tags: jquery, svg, reactjs

I have an SVG file that needs to be embedded inline so that its styling can be dynamically changed later based on certain conditions. Doing this in jQuery is fine, but I am using ReactJs.

So I would want to know how can we achieve this in a React component?

Ideally, what I would like to do is embed an external svg into a React component and then be able to manipulate the svg classes later when the state changes.

I tried using [Inline svg loader](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/react-inlinesvg) for react component, but there doesn't seem to be a way to manipulate the svg in any way.

Here is my code to better explain my situation,

```
var React = require('react');
var Isvg = require('react-inlinesvg');

var SvgContainer = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount : function(){

      console.log("component did update");

  var $svgComponentDom = $(this.refs.svgComponentRef);

  $svgdom = $(this.refs.svgComponentRef);
  console.log("jquery dom");
  console.log($svgdom);
  $svgdom.find("svg .unit").attr("class", "in-selection");
},

render: function(){
  var chosenBreakpoint = this.props.chosenBreakpoint;

  var svgNamePrefix = "master-";

 var svgUrl= window.baseUrl+'/images/'+svgNamePrefix+''+chosenBreakpoint+'.svg'; 

    return (

              <div className="svg-area" ref="svgComponentRef">
              <Isvg  src={svgUrl}>
                  Here's some optional content for browsers that don't support XHR or inline
                  SVGs. You can use other React components here too. Here, I'll show you.

              </Isvg>  
              </div>
    );
}
});
```

The embedded svg has a polygon element with a class `unit`. If I try to access it using `ref` and then try to add a class to it using jQuery it does not work. Am I missing something out?

Comment: The svg is just an element in the DOM. Have you tried getting a `ref` To the container or svg and manipulate it through DOM? Or, in the `render`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yes can do that but the problem is , i have several paths in the svg file that i am embedding and based on state changes i would like to add/modify different classes to some of them based on their ids. In jquery or something i would've directly accessed the necessary path element based on the id and manipulate its classes. But how can i do it here? At the most my container enclosing the svg can have a ref but these path elements don't have a ref to it to be accessible in react.

Comment: Without adding some code to your question to better explain the issue, I don't understand why you can't gain access to the elements of the SVG as you may have with jQuery.